# Can't push back to Github

Tags: git, github

I'm new to github, and keep running into basic errors. Most tutorials seem to be missing something here or there, or more probably it's me who's missing something... :)

My workflow:

```
"git init"
"git clone ... " (github url)
"git add ." (adds the entire directory.
```

I don't understand why I would need 
to `add` something that I just cloned... 
Isn't it obvious that these are the files I want to work with?)

```
"git commit -m" this works.
"git push" Now here the whole thing comes crashing down.
```

I would expect that when you clone something from github, the "`push`" command would push your changes right back.

But that does not seem to be the case. Git has no idea where my files came from? If I type `"git push origin master`" I get the error:

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
```

How do I create the push destination in such a way that it is exactly the same as where my files were cloned from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're initializing a new repo and then doing some cloning, which can be confusing...

Try:
1. moving to  fresh folder so your previous work doesn't create confusion
2.  `clone` from the github repo you want to work from
3. `cd` into that repo and `git status` to make sure everything is in order

You should only need to `add`, `commit`, and `push` after you've made changes. So try the rest of that workflow after you're sure you're in the repo you intended to clone. (instead of a new one you just created)

Update:
 Check out [Learn Git Branching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/), it's a great tutorial that helped me and a bunch of my colleagues.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seems to work! So I don't need to set the "origin" when I clone from Github and I can just use "git push" without adding "origin master" when I cloned something from Github?

Comment: Yes, because your push destination gets automatically configured when you clone. With `init`, you have to specify where you are pushing.

Comment: Adding tutorial I found useful way back, in case you would like to practice with more stuff.

Answer (score 2):

either run

```
git init
```

or

```
git clone ...
```

not both!

Comment: Thanks. I was following this tutorial from Github, which tells me to do both 'init' and 'clone' http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: @Kokodoko, that's not really a tutorial. It's more of a cheat sheet. You aren't expected to run each of those commands in that order, but rather to consider each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

commit & push generally works better after any modification.

You can also use git diff to find the difference between working directory & last commit.

GitHub also provide tools for ease (in case u often get confused with cmd)